# Add featured image programatically to custom post type

Tags: custom-post-types, post-thumbnails

I am trying to automatically add a video thumbnail from Vimeo or YouTube as the featured image when a new custom post type video is add/updated.
The video ID is an advanced custom field.
Here's my non-working code:

```
/**
 * Gets a vimeo thumbnail url
 * @param mixed $id A vimeo id (ie. 1185346)
 * @return thumbnail's url
*/
function getVimeoThumb($id) {
    $data = file_get_contents("http://vimeo.com/api/v2/video/".$id.".json");
    $data = json_decode($data);
    return $data[0]->thumbnail_large;
}

/**
 * Gets a youtube thumbnail url
 * @param mixed $id A youtube id
 * @return thumbnail's url
*/
function getYoutubeThumb($id) {
    $data = file_get_contents("https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos?key=AIzaSy...&part=snippet&id=".$id);
    $data = json_decode($data);
    return $json->items[0]->snippet->thumbnails->medium->url;
}

// Add featured image for videos
function addVideoThumb($post_ID) {

    if(!has_post_thumbnail($post_ID)):

        if(get_field("source", $post_ID) == "youtube"):
            $videoID = get_field("youtube_video_id", $post_ID);
            $imageURL = getYoutubeThumb($videoID);          
        else:
            $videoID = get_field("vimeo_video_id", $post_ID);
            $imageURL = getVimeoThumb($videoID);
        endif;
    
        //echo $imageURL;

        // download image from url
        $tmp = download_url($imageURL);

        $file = array(
            'name' => basename($imageURL),
            'tmp_name' => $tmp
        );

        // create attachment from the uploaded image
        $attachment_id = media_handle_sideload($file, $post_ID);

        // set the featured image
        update_post_meta($post_ID, '_thumbnail_id', $attachment_id);

    endif;
}
add_action('save_post_interel-tv-videos', 'addVideoThumb', 10, 3);
```

The function doesn't seem to be triggered at all as I tried to add a JavaScript alert to it and nothing pops up.
Any help?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Check out this [answer by Tom Nowell](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/46365/7355). Function [media_sideload_image](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/media_sideload_image) allows you to pass a URL to an image and uploads it to a `post_id`. That answer uses some hooks to assign that new image as a featured image which uses `_thumbnail_id`. by default.

Comment: Also doesn't work. Think the problem is the function not being triggered at all. But no idea why...

Comment: Where are you putting these functions and which functions aren't firing?

Comment: On `functions.php`

The function `addVideoThumb` assigned to the `add_action()` doesn't seem to be triggered when I update a video.

Comment: Found a couple of issues with the code. Will fix them and get back here.

Comment: Now, after fixing some switched variables on the code, there's some strange behaviour. The `addVideoThumb` runs when I click on add new video and not when I publish it. Weird... Running out of ideas here...

Answer (score 0):

Finally sorted it out.
As I am using Advanced Custom Fields, I need to use the `acf/save_post` hook with a priority greater than 10, so the `get_field()` functions are available.

Downside is that this hook runs for every post type. As opposed to the WP native `save_post` hook, with the ACF one you can't hook it for a specific custom post type.

So I also added a condition to check if the post is of type "interel-tv-videos", like `if(!has_post_thumbnail($post_ID) and get_post_type($post_ID) == "interel-tv-videos"):`